# from_json and as functions in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to run the example from the book "Stream processing with Apache Spark" chapter 7.

The code is published here: https://github.com/stream-processing-with-spark/notebooks/tree/master/chapter-7 in the streaming_weblogs.snb.ipynb .

It has no imports! and no .sbt file! That's why it is impossible to run the code for beginer.

I have problem with the second line:

```
val webLogSchema = Encoders.product[SchemaNasaWebLog].schema
val jsonStream = stream.select(from_json($"value"), webLogSchema) as "record")
val webLogStream = jsonStream.select("record.*").as[SchemaNasaWebLog]
```

> cannot resolve overrided method from_json
> cannot resolve symbol as

I have added before:

```
    import sparkSession.implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

but it is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the method signature being used is wrong.

Below reference shows how dependencies and packages are managed in Spark notebooks.

https://github.com/spark-notebook/spark-notebook/blob/master/docs/metadata.md

This has some examples on using spark streaming notebooks - https://github.com/spark-notebook/spark-notebook/tree/master/notebooks/streaming

Below doc shows how we can use from_json to parse complex json events and create dataframes out of it.

https://databricks.com/blog/2017/02/23/working-complex-data-formats-structured-streaming-apache-spark-2-1.html